# How to hide half of my table in a collapse

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

I have a table that loops each row through a foreach loop. After the fifth row, I need to hide the rest of the rows in a collapse so I do not take up to much real estate on page load.

Here is my code, any ideas?

```
{foreach from=$data.additional_results item=results key=renewal}
    {foreach from=$results item=result}
        {if ($renewal)}
            <tr class="renewal-{$renewal}">
        {else}
            <tr>
        {/if}
        {if $result.metric_name eq null}
                <td class="text-left-important">{$result.data_key}</td>
                <td>{$result.reference_goal}</td>
                <td>{$result.value}</td>
        {else}
                <td class="text-left-important" title="$result.data_key}">{$result.metric_name}</td>
                <td>{$result.reference_goal}</td>
                <td>{$result.value}</td>
        {/if}
            </tr>
    {/foreach}
{/foreachelse}
```

Comment: You may solve this issue by using the iterator variable provided by smarty. [See Smarty documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/de/language.function.foreach.tpl)

Answer (score 0):

You are concerned about your page load and still wants to load all data and display only few records.

In real, that will not make any performance optimization. because you are fetching all possible data and render the same in page.

If you are really concerned about speed then I would suggest to fetch only 5 rows and display the same. Additionally below those 5 rows you can place button to load more records.

Let me know if any doubt.